# AND Operation for -1

Tags: c++, boolean, implicit-conversion, type-promotion, logical-and

While implementing logical operations in the code, I discovered a phenomenon where it should not be entered in the if statement.
It turns out that this is the `AND (&&)` operation of -1 and natural numbers.

I don't know why the value 1 is printed in the same code below.
I ran direct calculations such as 1's complement and 2's complement, but no 1 came out.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = -1;
    
    int c = a && b;
    
    printf("test = %d",c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that `&&` is _logical_ AND, not _bitwise_ AND?

Comment: ... so `a && b` evaluates to `true`, == `1`.  To get what you were expecting, try `a & 1`

Comment: `a && b` gives a `bool`, whose value is `true` for non-zero value and `false` for zero. Then `true` will be outputted as `1` as `int`.

Comment: So are you saying that these return 0 OR 1, but return 1 because there is no value that is 0?

Comment: @SeongtaekOH They don't return 0 or 1, they return `false` or `true`. But there are conversions from the Boolean values to other types in various contexts (like when you try to printf them, false and true get converted to 0 and 1).

Comment: @SeongtaekOH Maybe you are getting confused between C++ and C, because your question says C++, but your code is (mostly) C. C and C++ have different rules in this case, so please be clear what language you are asking about.

Comment: @john the code is C++. In his implementation <iostream> ends up including <stdio.h> and therefore the code with printf compiles.

Comment: @Jabberwocky True but I wonder if he's getting his information from a book about C.

Comment: @john in both C and C++, `c` will be `1`.

Comment: No, I am using the C++ compiler and I have a problem while debugging an MFC project, so this is a simplified code.

Comment: @SeongtaekOH OK, well in C++ when you use `&&` what you get is a Boolean value, false or true, not an integer value 0 or 1. That's not the case in C (which was my point). But not relevant it seems.

Comment: yes (&&) returns true or false but
Actually I don't know why the result of -1 && 10 is true.

Comment: Because both -1 and 10 convert to `true` when used in a Boolean context

Comment: @SeongtaekOH `a && b` is true (or 1)  if `a` is different from 0 and if `b` is different from 0. Otherwise it is false (or 0).

Comment: @SeongtaekOH BTW what output did you expect?

Comment: *I don't know why the result of -1 && 10 is true*  Since `-1` is non-zero, it's treated as `true`, and since `10` is non-zero, it's treated as `true`.  Given `true && true`, the result of that expression is `true`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `a && b` is a `bool` type and is either `true` or `false`: it is `true` if and only if *both* `a` and `b` are non-zero, and `false` otherwise. As your question mentions complementing schemes (note that from C++20, an `int` is always 2's complement), -0 and +0 are both zero for the purpose of `&&`.

When assigned to the `int` type `c`, that `bool` type is converted implicitly to either 0 (if `false`) or 1 (if `true`).

(In C the analysis is similar except that `a && b` is an `int` type, and the implicit conversion therefore does not take place.)

Comment: It has been confirmed that if it is a negative number for int , it unconditionally returns true when it is converted to bool . thank you

Comment: @SeongtaekOH: With the exception of signed negative 0.

Comment: Isn't a conversion from int to bool also involved in the beginning? 'if and only if both a and b are non-zero'

Comment: @Sebastian: Conceptually in a way perhaps, although it's not possible to measure that with `decltype` or a series of overloaded functions.